# Loading Enhanced Volcano in R through BioConductor

Tags: r

Could someone please explain to me what this error means? I tried to load Enhanced Volcano from Bioconductor.

Below is my code and the associated error.

Code:

```
  if (!requireNamespace('BiocManager', quietly = TRUE))
       install.packages('BiocManager')

  BiocManager::install('EnhancedVolcano')
```

Error:

```
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see '?repositories' for 
 details

   replacement repositories:
       CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com/

   Bioconductor version 3.15 (BiocManager 1.30.20), R 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
   Installation paths not writeable, unable to update packages
      path: C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/library
      packages:
      boot, class, codetools, foreign, lattice, MASS, Matrix, mgcv, nlme, nnet, spatial, 
      survival
      Old packages: 'cli', 'clue', 'dplyr', 'rlang', 'tibble', 'utf8', 'vctrs', 'viridis'
       Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: library(EnhancedVolcano)
       Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: library(magrittr)
       Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: 
       a

      There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
       binary source needs_compilation
       viridis  0.6.2  0.6.3             FALSE

      trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/cli_3.6.1.zip'
      Content type 'application/zip' length 1331635 bytes (1.3 MB)
      downloaded 1.3 MB

      trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/clue_0.3-64.zip'
      Content type 'application/zip' length 997633 bytes (974 KB)
      downloaded 974 KB

      trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/dplyr_1.1.2.zip'
       Content type 'application/zip' length 1554793 bytes (1.5 MB)
       downloaded 1.5 MB

       trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/rlang_1.1.1.zip'
       Content type 'application/zip' length 1572046 bytes (1.5 MB)
       downloaded 1.5 MB

       trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/tibble_3.2.1.zip'
       Content type 'application/zip' length 690121 bytes (673 KB)
       downloaded 673 KB

       trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/utf8_1.2.3.zip'
       Content type 'application/zip' length 149861 bytes (146 KB)
       downloaded 146 KB

       trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/vctrs_0.6.2.zip'
       Content type 'application/zip' length 1335518 bytes (1.3 MB)
       downloaded 1.3 MB

       package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
       Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘cli’
       Warning: restored ‘cli’
       package ‘clue’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
       Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘clue’
       Warning: restored ‘clue’
       package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
       Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘dplyr’
       Warning: restored ‘dplyr’
       package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
       Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘rlang’
       Warning: restored ‘rlang’
       package ‘tibble’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
       Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘tibble’
       Warning: restored ‘tibble’
       package ‘utf8’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
       Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘utf8’
       Warning: restored ‘utf8’
       package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
       Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘vctrs’
       Warning: restored ‘vctrs’

       The downloaded binary packages are in
            C:\Users\djain\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0W8mOz\downloaded_packages
            installing the source package ‘viridis’

       trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/viridis_0.6.3.tar.gz'
       Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3049132 bytes (2.9 MB)
       downloaded 2.9 MB

      * installing *source* package 'viridis' ...
      ** package 'viridis' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
      ** using staged installation
      ** R
      ** data
      *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
      ** inst
      ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
         Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
         namespace 'rlang' 1.0.6 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
         Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImport -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> 
         loadNamespace
         Execution halted
         ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'viridis'
         * removing 'C:/Users/djain/.RLibrary/viridis'
         * restoring previous 'C:/Users/djain/.RLibrary/viridis'

         The downloaded source packages are in
            ‘C:\Users\djain\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0W8mOz\downloaded_packages’
         Warning messages:
         1: package(s) not installed when version(s) same as or greater than current; use 
             `force = TRUE` to re-install: 'EnhancedVolcano' 
         2: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
              problem copying C:\Users\djain\.RLibrary\00LOCK\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll to 
         C:\Users\djain\.RLibrary\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll: Permission denied
         3: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
            problem copying C:\Users\djain\.RLibrary\00LOCK\clue\libs\x64\clue.dll to 
         C:\Users\djain\.RLibrary\clue\libs\x64\clue.dll: Permission denied
         4: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
            problem copying C:\Users\djain\.RLibrary\00LOCK\dplyr\libs\x64\dplyr.dll to 
            C:\Users\djain\.RLibrary\dplyr\libs\x64\dplyr.dll: Permission denied
         5: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
            problem copying C:\Users\djain\.RLibrary\00LOCK\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll to 
         C:\Users\djain\.RLibrary\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied
         6: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
            problem copying C:\Users\djain\.RLibrary\00LOCK\tibble\libs\x64\tibble.dll to 
         C:\Users\djain\.RLibrary\tibble\libs\x64\tibble.dll: Permission denied
         7: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
            problem copying C:\Users\djain\.RLibrary\00LOCK\utf8\libs\x64\utf8.dll to 
         C:\Users\djain\.RLibrary\utf8\libs\x64\utf8.dll: Permission denied
         8: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
            problem copying C:\Users\djain\.RLibrary\00LOCK\vctrs\libs\x64\vctrs.dll to 
         C:\Users\djain\.RLibrary\vctrs\libs\x64\vctrs.dll: Permission denied
         9: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, repos = repos,  :
            installation of package ‘viridis’ had non-zero exit status
             >
```

Sorry for the whole code, however, I am unsure how to interpret this error in R. I am not a heavy R user but need to develop a volcano plot with gene names, log2fold change and P-value.

Comment: Try launching RStudio as an administrator and see whether the packages and can updated and installed to the selected location. Otherwise, you could change your library location to a folder which isn't protected.